# How to save two models in Yii2?

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii2

I have subscribe form where just 2 fields `fio` and `email`. I have default generated `SubscribeForm` model which return `tableName = inf_users`.

I get POST data, work with it and save to `inf_users` well. But now, i need to add the values to table `act_courses` after `model->save` previous table with structure:

- id (PK)
- ser_id (FK)
- course_id (FK)
- status (FK)
- action_date (DATE)

What the table? I store all actions (orders) of users (online school). But now i have not working code without errors.

```
$model = new SubscribeForm();
$password = generateStrongPassword(12);
$model->password = md5($password);
$infUsersStatuses = $model->getStatuses('inf_users');
$model->status = $infUsersStatuses[0]->id;
$model->reg_date = date('Y-m-d');

if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $actCoursesModel = new ActCourses();
    $infUser = $model->find()->where(['email' => Yii::$app->request->post('SubscribeForm')['email']])->one();
    $actCoursesModel->user_id = $infUser['id'];
    $actCoursesModel->course_id = $this->courseID;
    $actCoursesStatuses = $model->getStatuses('act_courses');
    $actCoursesModel->status = $actCoursesStatuses[0]->id;
    $actCoursesModel->action_date = date('Y-m-d');

    if ($model->save() && $actCoursesModel->save()) {
      ///someactions
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have data in `inf_users`, but no data in `act_courses`.

Thanks a lot!

P.S.
`getStatuses('act_courses')` - return all available values which i can use for table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > What am I doing wrong? I have data in inf_users, but no data in act_courses

Where are variable $act_courses definition, also $inf_users?

second:

```
$infUser = $model->find()->where(...);
```

Find before save?

third:

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
```

load after assign some data?

Comment: I do not use this variable. Where did you fin it? `act_courses` is a table

Comment: Understood/ See another  (2 & 3) things.

Comment: Thanks for line `Find before save?`

Comment: Welcome! 3 is also important thing. if i POST to form `status`, i`ll override your previous asignment for example, ) Good luck!